# How to sync changes done to remote repo on diff computer?

Tags: git, github, versioning

I have the following situtation:

- I have a remote repo and it is cloned on Computer 1.
- I also have a remote repo and it is cloned on Computer 2.
- On Computer 1, I do some changes to my files and then push it back to
  the remote repo.

Now when I work on Computer 2, 
**How do I sync the local repo with the newly made changes in the remote repo?**

Comment: Is the remote repo the same between the two computers?

Comment: Yes :) They are the same repo

Comment: Or are you just looking for `git pull`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the question, but I'm going to assume that the remote repo for both computers 1 and 2 are the same, and that the repo is cloned to both machines.

Then to sync changes from computer 1 to 2, you can simply push the changes from 1 to the remote repo, then you can fetch or pull them to 2:

```
# From computer 1
git push <remote> <branch>

# From computer 2
git fetch <remote>
git checkout <branch>
git merge <remote>/<branch>

# Or do the above in 2 steps
git checkout <branch>
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

These are Git basics that you can read about from [the link that dzada posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580188/how-to-sync-changes-done-to-remote-repo-on-diff-computer/18580222#18580222), [Git Basics - Working with Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes). I highly recommend that you read that and the other chapters in the book, in particular chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5. It's a **FREE online book**.

Comment: Bingo! Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Add the repository from computer X to the repo on computer Y directly without passing from your central one. See here, how to add a connection directly between X and Y.

X ----  central / origin ------- Y

more documentation here :http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes